# Средний промежуток между операциями обращения к серверу

Tags: ping, ddos, http, сервер

**Всем доброго дня!**

*Интересует такой вопрос:* предположим, есть некоторое клиентское приложение, которое должно как можно чаще запрашивать у сервера небольшую (до 1кб) актуальную порцию данных. Какой наименьший интервал между двумя операциями обращения к серверу (установки повторного соединения)  был бы наиболее подходящим? Т.е. не слишком малым, чтобы не произошел DDoS в случае наличия множества клиентских приложений, пингующих сервер, и не слишком большим, чтобы полученную информацию можно было бы назвать актуальной. На данный момент пинг происходит с промежутком в 3 секунды. Можно ли это число уменьшить и до какого значения?

**P.S.**
О характеристиках серверной части: на данный момент это обычный виртуальный хостинг, т.е. никакого VPS.

**Спасибо.**

Comment: Зависит от пропускной способности приложения и ресурсов сервера. Можете попробовать найти это значение с помощью соседнего сервера и Apache Benchmarks, но я бы не стал на него полагаться.

Comment: А так ли важно получать эти данные в режиме реального времени? Быть может, стоит наоборот уменьшить период опроса, немного изменив логику?

И приложение - html или flash/php/desktop/etc? Если последнее, может данные тогда отправлять не через http, а по tcp? Аналогично и для html можно сделать, если немного поколдовать. Тогда ping не так часто будет нужен - разрыв соединения вы и так почти всегда ловить будете (у нас иногда это не определялось, решалось пингом раз в 30 минут; детали точно не знаю, т.к. СИшники с этим сталкивались).

Лучше бы вы и саму задачу описали, а не только проблему. ))

Comment: @BOPOH, 
1) нет, логику менять не следует

2) задачу описывать не вижу смысла, ибо она уже решена, и меня интересует лишь тот аспект, что затронут в самом вопросе.

Comment: @0xFFh, задачу можно решить тысячью способами. Не факт, что выбранный вами - идеальный. Возможно, немного изменив подход, удастся избежать кучу проблем.

А задачу я просил только для того, чтобы было ясно, насколько быстро вам действительно нужно обновление. Одно дело - военные спутники в режиме онлайн, другое дело - обновление списка лидеров в простенькой игре.

Хотя на старых радарах обновление данных вроде как происходило даже реже, чем раз в секунду.

Comment: @BOPOH, вся необходимая информация дана. Вас интересует еще что-то, что касается технической части?

Comment: Если информация меняется редко (а Вам нужно отслеживать сам факт ее изменения), то можно просто отдавать каждый раз не все, а просто стандартный ответ 304 (данные не менялись). Если данные однотипны для всех пользователей (или их к примеру 10-20), то данные можно формировать статикой и дать nginx'у, пусть раздает. Он это будет делать хорошо (да и апач тоже справиться).

В целом, если частоту запросов к серверу нет смысла делать выше, чем половина периода обновления данных на самом сервере.

Answer (score 1):

А может лучше [long polling](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128535/)?